# Android, AnimatorListener. При рекурсивном вызове animatorSet в AnimatorListener не вызывается метод onAnimationEnd

Tags: android, анимация

Начал изучать Android и хочу написать заставку, в которой будут анимированно выводиться цифры от 5 до 1 и переходить в другую Activity.

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
    final AnimatorSet animatorSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.splash_animator);
    animatorSet.setTarget(text);
    animatorSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            if(text.getText().toString().compareTo("1") == 0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.alpha_in, R.anim.alpha_out);
            } else {
                text.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString()) - 1));
                animator.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

        }
    });
    animatorSet.start();
}
}
```

Когда запускаю приложение он правильно показывает 5 и 4, но потом встает и ничего не делает. Отладка показала, что когда animatorSet вызывается второй раз, у Listener не срабатывает метод onAnimationEnd. Может кто подсказать, что я неправильно делаю?

Comment: Попробуй не рекурсивный вывод а задать определенное кол-во повторений анимации android:repeatCount

Comment: А как мне в таком случае изменять цифры и переходить на другой экран?

Comment: я не проверял, но у Вас в коде есть два метода onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) и onAnimationEnd(Animator animator). Можно их использовать